# smartgwt filter editor problem

Tags: smartgwt

i am using Listgrid of smartgwt api. i have set filter editor on the list grid using **setShowFilterEditor()**. On UI, i can filter out the text from the particular columns using filter editor which is shown on top of listgrid. till this, everything works fine. but problem starts after this. my ListGridRecords are of type ScreenInstanceGridRecord.

I cleared out the **filter criteria** before getting the **ListGridRecord** from the ListGrid using method **clearCriteria()**, so that i can save all the records to database ie. **unfiltered records**. when i try to get records from the listgrid using **getRecordList()**, 1000 **Dummy records** are added on the fly on first iteration, all my populated records are ignored . and i need here is records of **ScreenInstanceGridRecord** type. but on second iteration, i am getting my populated records which is of **ScreenInstanceGridRecord** type. why this problem is occurring. i should be getting ScreenInstanceGridRecord on the first iteration itself when i try to get **records** from the ListGrid using **getRecordList()**. i am getting no idea about this weird thing. any help from your side is most welcome.. plss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you're getting 1000 Dummy records instead of your loaded records, in fact, your Records are not loaded yet at all.  In this case, the ResultSet created by the ListGrid (see docs for ListGrid.fetchData()) is returning a provisional length (defaults to 1000) and returning the loading marker in lieu of Records (see ResultSet.rowIsLoaded()).

Use the DataArrived event to take action once data has been loaded.  See ResultSet.lengthIsKnown() for how you can, in general, tell that data is not yet loaded.